# SQLite - Retrieving image from database and showing in ImageView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have stored an image into my database as a `byteArray` and as a `blob`, however I am unable to show the image in an `ImageView` when I try to access it again. I get this message

> Couldn't read row 0, col 4 from CursorWindow.

Here is my code:

**Home.java**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData2();
    if(data.moveToNext() && data.getCount() > 0){
        byte[] image = data.getBlob(4);
        Bitmap finalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(finalImage);
    }
 }
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public boolean addEntryImage(byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL5,image);
    long result = database.insert( TABLE_NAME, null, cv );

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
public Cursor getData2(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //String query = "SELECT " + COL5 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("select * from profile_table", null);
    return data;
}
```

All help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

would you take data.moveToNext() out of if block.Then try again

Comment: Once I take that out I get an error of `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 9`

Comment: try this.. delete data.moveToNext() and then try if(data != null && data.moveToFirst()){byte[] image = data.getBlob(4);
        Bitmap finalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(finalImage); data.close();}

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but when I try that I get this, `Failed to read row 0, column 4 from a CursorWindow which has 9 rows, 2 columns.`

Comment: upgrade db version 1 to 2.